# sql query inserting auto_incremented value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have a table that looks kinda like this:

```
ID - (int) Auto_increment 
Name - (varchar) 
LastName - (varchar)
```

How do I go about adding a row to this table with the `auto_increment` value?,

By just typing

```
insert into table_name ([Name], [LastName]) 
values("asdasd", "asdasd")
```

it doesn't seem to get an `ID` for that row.

Do I need to add ID to the insert string without value or should it work as I wrote it?

Comment: I'm using SqlCE (compact edition) in a C# project in VS2012.

Comment: Does this help? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/5276cb88-e756-4926-ad5d-32d68611054c/

Comment: please show the create table script.

Comment: That would work out of the box if column is identity.

Answer (score 2):

Just ignore this `auto_increment` field in the insert statement list of fields like  what you posted in your question:

```
insert into table_name ([Name], [LastName]) values("asdasd", "asdasd")
```

This should an auto increment value for the field `ID`.

Comment: Thats what I thought but it doesen't seem to show up.. Maybe theres something wrong with my function that displays the data from the database then. But it shouldn't be, which is why Im asking this question to begin with.

Comment: @Jacco, How this doesn't work?? Check your database table from the Database management studio you are using, and check the values inserted into it.

Comment: Yep, just did and it does work, the ID just wont display for some reason in my program.

Comment: @Jacco, Check your database  table directly form the database management studio first not from your program. May be there is something wrong in your program. And also try this insert statement directly into the database management studio.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the ID column is auto_increment? your insert statement is correct for what you want to do.

```
insert into table_name ([Name], [LastName]) 
values("asdasd", "asdasd")
```

just check for de ID column properties to see if it really is auto_increment.

Comment: Yup, it is.. well I got what I wanted, confirmation, guess there must be something wrong with the way I display the ID field then. Doubble checked and there is in fact an ID in the database just that it wont display. Thanks